# Calling a mootools class method from another external function

Tags: javascript, class, mootools

I've got a legacy mootools class I'm using that has many functions. Instead of extending the class, I'm trying to simply call one of the class methods from outside the class. So if the class looked something like this:

```
var myClass = new Class({
    search: function(){
        this.searchSpinner.show();
        this.request.send({data: this.data});
    },

    // many other functions
})
```

I need to call the `search` method from another script loaded on the same page.

Right now I'm trying like this:

```
window.myClass.search();
```

But this results in a big hairy error that I can't make sense of but which looks like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){e(this);if(g.$prototyping){return this;}this.$caller=null;var i=(this.initialize)?this.initialize.apply(this,arguments):this;this.$caller=this.caller=null;
return i;} has no method 'search'
```

Is there a 'right' way to call this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class as defined using Mootool's `Class` does not behave quite like a static class in other languages. In order to access methods in that class, you'll have to create an instance of that class first:

```
var classObj = new myClass(/*any parameters if required, check the "initialize" method*/);
classObj.search();
```

Comment: If I've missed anything, I'm sure @dimitar-christoff will be around sooner or later with more information :)

Comment: Hi Julian-- yes, Dimitar is the man with mootools! So you're saying inside my "calling" script, I need to create a new instance of the myClass class, and then search against it? I'll give that a shot. Thanks

Comment: +1 agreed. you are creating an object constructor prototype - you need to instantiate it to use it.

Comment: having said that, you can call to the prototype directly in some cases. like `myClass.prototype.search.call(someobj)` - depends on host obj and api of method if it will work

Comment: @DimitarChristoff-- the `myClass.prototype.search.call(someobj)` successfully called the method, but I'm getting `undefined` errors probably due to the use of `this`. I tried using `bind(this)` after the method, but this fails too. Any other advice?

Comment: what i just said, depends on the method. clearly here it relies on the host object having a `searchSpinner` instance and a `request` instance - which the prototype does not. you need to do what Julian said - instantiate the class into a new object and call it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply a "singleton" pattern : if you will be using only one occurrence of this class, you can use :

```
var mySingleton = new new Class({
```

(notice the 2 x `new` keyword) then

```
mySingleton.search()
```

to call it...

oh and if you trying to add static functions to a mootools class, just declare them like that :

```
var myClass = new Class({ });
myClass.staticMethod = function() {
    // ...
};
```

hope this helps !

Comment: @Romain-- what does the `new new` syntax mean in practice? Thanks!

Comment: well, you basically create a new instance of the class right away (and loose the ability to create other instances)… You end up with a kind of mootools singleton pattern! it the same than doing :
var myclass = new Class();
var myinstance = new myclass();